# Fastest way to replace values in a Pandas column using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a quite large dataset (+150M rows) and I want to replace some values in a column with corresponding dictionary keys.

What I have looks like this:

```
col1
John
John Marvin
Lucas
Name:Lucas
Mary
Mary Surname
```

And I am trying to make it look like this

```
col1
John
John 
Lucas
Lucas
Mary
Mary
```

The number of different values in `col1` is not that large so I thought in creating a dictionary assigning the correct values for all those that are odd.

```
d = {'John Marvin' = 'John', 'Name:Lucas' = 'Lucas', 'Mary Surname' = 'Mary'}
```

Given the lenght of my dataset I am trying to find a fast way to do this, does anyone have an idea of what could be a good way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: df,col1.repalce(d,inplace=True)

Comment: `df['col1'].replace(d)` after fixing your `d` to a dictionary which cannot have `=`

Comment: change your dict to `d  = {'John Marvin' : 'John', 'Name:Lucas' : 'Lucas', 'Mary Surname' : 'Mary'}` @anky can u close i marked the dupe